# Visual Studio 2013: Output of project path that depends on output path of another project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

Working in Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

Have two projects under one solution. Project one is start-up and its Build output path is set to `bin\x86\Debug\`. Project two is library project, and its B. o. path should be `bin\x86\Debug\Plugins`. Is it possible to set Project two B. o. path to depend on the B. o. path of the Project One ? 
I can go into Project Two properties and manually set the B. o. path, but if I change path for Project one, I have to change path for Project two as well.

Comment: That's why projects get built to the *solution* directory.  Default setting is `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\`

Comment: Ok... And what is the question here?

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose? You imply that you don't want to specify the output directory yet you want it in a specific location chosen by you.

If it's a scaling problem, where you don't want to change the same thing in many similar projects, the answer is to use a property page.